# Calling gdal2tiles.py in AWS LAMBDA function

Tags: aws-lambda, gdal

I'm trying to call [gdal2tiles.py](https://gdal.org/programs/gdal2tiles.html#gdal2tiles-py) in AWS Lambda function using [GeoLambda](https://github.com/developmentseed/geolambda) layer.
I can't figure out how to call this script form the lambda function.

My lambda function looks like this so far:

```py
    import json
    import os
    from osgeo import gdal
    def lambda_handler(event, context):
       
         os.system("gdal2tiles.py -p -z [0-6] test.jpg")
```

In the log I have this error: **sh: gdal2tiles.py: command not found**

Any idea how to solve this? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one way to do it is to `import gdal2tiles` utilities from the `GeoLambda` layer that  you added to your lambda function.

For example:

```
gdal2tiles.generate_tiles('/path/to/input_file', '/path/to/output_dir/'), nb_processes=2, zoom='0-6')
```

Read more about in [gdal2tiles](https://pypi.org/project/gdal2tiles/)

**Edit:**
Ok i made it to work with these set of layer attached to the lambda.
The first 2 layers were straight from the Github

> - arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:552188055668:layer:geolambda-python:3
> - arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:552188055668:layer:geolambda:4

The 3rd layer is our `gdal2tiles` which is created locally and attached to lambda fucntion

> - arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:246990787935:layer:gdaltiles:1

you can download the zip from [here](https://github.com/pmrubenrao/Lambda-Layer-Gdal2tiles)

[image]

And i hope you added the below `Environment vairable` to your lambda function configuration

- GDAL_DATA=/opt/share/gdal
- PROJ_LIB=/opt/share/proj (only needed for GeoLambda 2.0.0+)

Comment: Thanks Ruben, I'm new to Python, could you precise from what module to import? I've an error: No module named 'gdal2tiles' if I use  'import gdal2tiles'

Comment: If the layer that you added to your lambda function has these libs than it should have recognizes it.
But i did try to import the gdal2tiles lib using the layer arn provided in the Geolambda github page and  it  fails for mee too.
I suggest you try to build your own layers and give a shot.
But the main idea behind the Lambda layers is the same "you add it to your lambda function and use it"
[Create lambda layers](https://medium.com/the-cloud-architect/getting-started-with-aws-lambda-layers-for-python-6e10b1f9a5d)

Comment: @Philiz updated the answer, give it a try